# Hide div when click outside the area with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide div content when clicking outside of it. I read a lot of topics on the subject but I can't make it work.

Here is the `div` I want to hide :

```
<div class="menu_content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>      
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>  <!-- END ROW-->
        </div>
    </div><!-- END CONTAINER FLUID-->
</div>
```

I'm not an expert in Javascript, so if you have simple sample code to achieve this, it could be great.

I tried the following code but it does not work :

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if($(this) != $(".menu_main_content")) {
        $(".menu_main_content").hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the html of the code that opens the DIV content :

```
 <div class="menu_main_button">
        <img href=""src="{{ asset('images/icons/icon_menu_home.png') }}"  alt="" />
</div>
```

The button opens the DIV with .menu_main_content class.

So the fact of clicking on the button is considered as outside the DIV. That's my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably one for `e.stopPropagation` :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmxEXN?editors=101)

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

  $('.menu_content').hide();
});

$('.menu_content').click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I read that stop propagation has to be avoided if possible. Is it right ?

Comment: Can't think of any general reason why that would be the case myself... it could only become an issue when a parent of the element has a click handler as well.

Comment: I completed my original question with the html code that opens the DIV concerned.

Comment: So the propagation does not work. The problem here is that there are two separate DIV. With only one div, your solution coud work.

Comment: `$('.menu_content, .menu_main_button').click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation()});`

Comment: Then the above should solve that, if I understand the situation correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works. Weel done ! Thanks a lot. I will close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` always refers to `document` and I *think* you can't compare elements like that. Try checking if the given element is hovered, if not, hide it:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if (!$(".menu_main_content").is(":hover")) {
        $(".menu_main_content").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: As in `$(document).click(function(e) {  if(e.target != $(".menu_main_content")[0]) { ...`?

Comment: No really...Target could be child of `$(".menu_main_content")` element!

Comment: Isn't checking `.is(":hover")` more intuitive than trying to check if the target is any of the child-elements?

Comment: And hovering doesn't trigger on touch devices.

Comment: Both valid points, feel free to suggest another answer. Should I delete or edit this one?

Comment: I tried the solution of Streetlamp but it does not work as expected in fact. This kind of fonctionality always seems to be strangely hard :)